# using oracle when join two subqueries together changed the contents of the first query

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

when i tried to join two subqueries together, the value in first query changed. Any idea why? Thanks!

here is the code:

```
SELECT *
FROM    ((

     SELECT HOME, VISITOR, COUNT("result") AS HGOALS
     FROM(
         SELECT HOME, VISITOR, "result"
         FROM ENGLAND
         WHERE TIER = 1 AND "SEASON" >= 1980 AND "result" = 'H'
         )
     GROUP BY HOME, VISITOR
     ORDER BY HGOALS DESC)
             JOIN
     (SELECT HOME, VISITOR, COUNT("result") AS AGOALS
     FROM(
         SELECT HOME, VISITOR, "result"
         FROM ENGLAND
         WHERE TIER = 1 AND "SEASON" > 1980 AND "result" = 'A'
         )
     GROUP BY HOME, VISITOR) USING (VISITOR, HOME))
     ORDER BY AGOALS DESC;
```

the part of output is

```
     Manchester United  Aston Villa 5   18
     Arsenal    West Ham United 5   17
     Arsenal    Aston Villa 6   17
     Manchester United  Everton 12  16
     Liverpool  Aston Villa 8   16
```

but when i execute only the first part of JOIN, which is

```
     SELECT HOME, VISITOR, COUNT("result") AS HGOALS
     FROM(
         SELECT HOME, VISITOR, "result"
         FROM ENGLAND
         WHERE TIER = 1 AND "SEASON" >= 1980 AND "result" = 'H'
         )
     GROUP BY HOME, VISITOR
     ORDER BY HGOALS DESC
```

the part of result is:

```
     Manchester United  Tottenham Hotspur   27
     Arsenal    Everton 26
     Manchester United  Aston Villa 26
     Liverpool  Tottenham Hotspur   25
     Manchester United  West Ham United 24
```

note that for

```
     Manchester United  Aston Villa 5   18
     Manchester United  Aston Villa 26
```

the result I should get is 26, but it changed to 5 when I join two subqueries together.
why?

Comment: Thanks Ella Guan.  I'm not seeing why the `count` in the first subquery could chang by joining to the second, as each `count` is executed inlining before the `join`.  If possible could you post the backing data (for Manchester United at home vs Aston Villa)?  Also could you please run the below variant query and let me know the result for this matchup?  `SELECT HOME, VISITOR, COUNT(DECODE(RESULT,'H',RESULT,NULL)) AS HGOALS, COUNT(DECODE(RESULT,'A',RESULT,NULL)) AS AGOALS FROM ENGLAND WHERE TIER = 1 AND SEASON >= 1980 GROUP BY VISITOR, HOME;`  Also why >= 1980 for 'H' but > 1980 for 'A'?

Comment: Sorry the backing data is too long to put in the comment box. Basically there are 26 times that Manchester defeats Aston Villa as a home team. And I run this: SELECT HOME,VISITOR,COUNT(DECODE("result",'H',"result",NULL)) AS HGOALS, COUNT(DECODE("result",'A',"result",NULL)) AS AGOALS FROM ENGLAND WHERE TIER = 1 AND SEASON >= 1980 AND HOME = 'Manchester United' AND VISITOR = 'Aston Villa' GROUP BY VISITOR, HOME; The result is: Manchester United Aston Villa 26 2. And actually I don't know why but I can only get the result that matches the given answer when I put > 1980 for 'A' not >= 1980.

Answer (score 0):

My your query is so complicated.  Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT HOME, VISITOR,
       SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HGOALS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AGOALS
FROM ENGLAND
WHERE TIER = 1 AND SEASON >= 1980 
GROUP BY HOME, VISITOR
ORDER BY AGOALS DESC;
```

Note:  You may need the quotes around `result`, depending on how the column is defined.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your query but I still get "5" but not "26" on HGOALS.

Comment: I suspect the problem is a misinterpretation of the data.  Clearly, the `join` in your original query is not the issue.

Comment: I'll double check that. Thank you!